# How to navigate directly to specific version of API in swagger-ui via Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I want to link to the swagger doc for specific API versions from a separate site. Can I pre-select the DiscoverySelector using a url route?

For example, it'd be great if I could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="~/swagger/ui/v1.0"> My API 1.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/swagger/ui/v2.0"> My API 2.0</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I am using Web API 2, so I have to use the Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and this is a feature of Swagger-ui not Swashbuckle:

Here are examples:

- http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=http://swagger-net-test-multiapiversions.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1_0
- http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=http://swagger-net-test-multiapiversions.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V2_0

Here is the multiversion  site:

http://swagger-net-test-multiapiversions.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Comment: links are invalid  {"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file http://swagger-net-test-multiapiversions.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V2_0"}]}